# SSRS Parameter hidden expression error while hiding the tablix

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am getting below error . When I am hiding using parameter from hidden expression.

```
Expression:=IIF(Parameters!BU.Value="BU5",False,True)
```

```
[The Hidden expression for the tablix ‘BU’ contains an error: Overload resolution failed because no Public '=' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Shared Operator =(a As String, b As String) As Boolean':
        Argument matching parameter 'a' cannot convert from 'Object()' to 'String'. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)][1]
```

[image]

Please help to solve this issue.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is your expression really like `Expression:=IIF(Parameters!BU.Value="BU5",False,True)`?  If so, you need to do it without the `Expression:` part.  Otherwise, I would check to see if there's any custom code in your report that could be causing issues.

Comment: My custom code part is empty. I would be do this with expression only because I am having multiple value parameters.i need to show or hide based on each Parameter value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like BU is a multi-valued parameter.  If you want to compare the parameter value to a string directly, you will have to change it to only allow a single selection; otherwise you are comparing an array to a string, which is what your error message indicates.

Another option is to use the JOIN function to create a concatenated list of the selections to compare against in your expression.  For example, you could hide a column if 'BK5' is not selected in the BU parameter by setting the column's visibility expression as follows:

```
=INSTR("|" & JOIN(Parameters!BU.Value,"|") & "|","|BK5|")=0
```

Keep in mind that if you use this method, best practice dictates that you should pick a delimiter that you do not expect to appear in the available values for the parameter, so proceed at your own risk in that regard.

Comment: yes, I am having multi-valued parameter . can you please give any example how to implement JOIN function to create a concatenated. Thanks

Comment: @Raj Esh, I have edited my answer to include an example.